# How do I increase the amount of electrons transferred in a battery?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrons

I made a simple battery with $\ce{Al}$ as anode electrode with $\pu{0.7 M}$ aluminum sulfate electrolyte. Platinum is my cathode electrode with $\pu{2 x 10^-4 M}$ $\ce{KOH}$ solution. I am generating $\ce{85 mA}$ (my cell produced $\pu{0.04 V}$ under a $\pu{47 \Omega}$ load). How can I increase amount of electrons to increase the current produced by my cell?

My half cell reactions are 
\begin{align}
\ce{2Al &-> 2Al^3+ + 6e-}\\
\ce{3H2O + 6e- &-> 3H2 + 6OH-}
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your setup, and some more details of the shape/configuration/etc. of your electrodes? As the question sits, there's not enough information to help you debug your apparatus.

Comment: simply increasing your electrode areas by either physically using large electrodes, or by sandpapering your electrode surfaces to make rougher surfaces should help. I do agree with hby2py though, more details would help in debugging.

Comment: Please note that the proper term for "number of moles" is [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html). The former would be the same as referring to the mass as "number of kilograms".

Comment: Have you acidified your aluminum sulfate electrolyte at all? Are you stirring either electrolyte chamber?

Comment: Also, why are you chilling your KOH?

Comment: yes, I stirred both the solutions. I did not acidify the aluminum sulfate solution. The addition of aluminum sulfate to water made the pH decrease. I just wanted to know how the KOH will react under a lower temperature